# How can I pass this callback in Angular and update $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm writing a basic game app in AngularJS. The game has `room` objects, some of which contain `enemy` objects. I have a function to `moveRoom()` which takes a callback parameter to run if the room contains an `enemy`.

Inside this callback function, my `$scope` changes don't register on `ng-show` elements. I've tried combinations of `$scope.apply()` and `$scope.digest()` to no avail:

```
$scope.moveToRoom = function (newRoom) {
    // the callback here is only triggered if roomToMoveTo contains an enemy
    manager.setCurrentRoom(roomToMoveTo, function($scope, encounterType, data) {
        $scope.apply(function() {
            if (encounterType === 'enemy') {
                $scope.encounterMode = true;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

... and the `setCurrentRoom()` function (defined in another module) looks like this:

```
var setCurrentRoom = function (room, callback) {
    $scope.currentRoom = room;

    if (callback) {
        var enemies = room.getEnemies();
        if (enemies.length > 0) {
            callback($scope, 'enemy', enemies);
        }
    }

    return $scope.currentRoom;
};
```

(You can see I've tried passing `$scope` to the callback function but this hasn't helped).

The error I get is `Error: $scope.apply is not a function`, or if I remove that, I get no UI changes (that I'd expect from `ng-show="encounterMode"`).

Only thing that I can think of that might be breaking things is the way I share `$scope` between modules – the `manager` module is another file loaded via requireJS – it returns a function which takes a `$scope` parameter, so I initialise the `manager` module with `$scope` so all its methods have access to the global scope. Not sure if there's a better way to do this when mixing Angular with AMD JavaScript.

Is there something I'm missing here about making this callback update the scope? Am I passing it wrongly?

EDIT: As TJ points out, I have a typo which should be `$apply` – having fixed this, I'm now seeing [Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply). Have a feeling I'm still approaching this wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a typo. `apply` code should be `$apply`

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
//-----^ this thing
```

Comment: Doh! Although fixing that introduces this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply

Comment: @MattAndrews That means something triggered apply and you don't need to trigger it manually..?

Comment: ... you're right. Changing my view logic to `<div  ng-hide="!encounterMode">` fixed it. Thanks!